# Run an application as Administrator with predefined username and password

Tags: c#, windows, file-io, permissions, administrator

In my application I have some Save methods that store data on user's hard disk. How could it be possible to prevent the user from getting access, change or delete that files as soon as the application can still access, change and delete that files?

The possible solution is running the application As Administrator on a limited user who don't have access to the save folder but with a predefined Username and Password of the system administrator which stored in application.

I've read other topics to work with UAC, Application Manifest.

As I mentioned in Title ***Is it possible to run a program as administrator without user interaction?***

EDIT 1: I'm looking for a solution that works on all version of windows(XP, Vista and Seven)

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do this? I'm asking because it matters whether you want to prevent access by the user, or to prevent access by other programs run by the user. If the former, just give up now, it's not going to work. If the latter, it's possible, but unless you're very careful with how you go about it, it's a security risk.

Comment: The PCs are built to work for my pragram and there is no other program so I want to prevet the access by the user.

Comment: In that case, if the user isn't supposed to run other programs anyway, it seems like it would be easier to prevent access to other programs.

Comment: You mean prevent access to Windows Explorer? It's not what I looking for

Comment: The programs that do things like this are almost always of the malicious variety. You're trying to subvert system security measures without a compelling reason.

Comment: Malicious or hacky behavior is not important in my solution because there is no other program installed  on the machine and no Antivirus and no Internet connectivity. The important part is preventing the user from changing the files.

Comment: To do what you're asking for, write a launcher application that uses  CreateProcessWithLogonW (with a known admin username and password) to start the real application.  Be warned that a competent user will be able to extract the admin credentials and log on as the administrator.  Ben's answer (a split application) is the proper approach.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Please submit your comment as an answer so I can select it as the answer of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HarryJohnston said in comments:

*"To do what you're asking for, write a launcher application that uses CreateProcessWithLogonW (with a known admin username and password) to start the real application. Be warned that a competent user will be able to extract the admin credentials and log on as the administrator. Ben's answer (a split application) is the proper approach."*

And it's my selected answer.

Comment: @HarryJohnston is correct, you should use a split application. If you are doing this you have given the user unsupervised administrative access. For example, if you application has a "file open" or "file save" dialog, it is trivial to browse to CMD.EXE, right-click, and choose "run". Then the user has a command prompt with administrative permissions. ***At least make it a specially created user account e.g. MYAPP_USR not an administrative account***.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have investigated the capabilities of ACLs and you cannot make them meet your needs. For example you can set an ACL which allows any user to create a file, any user to modify or delete a file they created, but not modify or delete other user's files.

---

The correct way to solve this problem is to have the applicaton split into two parts. One is running as a windows Service, Activate-As-Configured-User DCOM server or other elevated process, the other is running as the dumb-old-user.

When the client application wishes to carry out an action which requires elevation, it passes the request to the elevated half of the application. This will perform any security checks, application logic checks, etc, which are required, then carry out the action.

In this way you can prevent the user going in though the back door and messing up your application data. However it doesn't really help with them messing up the data through the FRONT door.

Comment: Your first solution with ACL does not meet my needs as One windows user is working with both my program and windows so whatever can do in one role, can do in another.

Comment: For your second solution could you give some source or workaround to work with?

Comment: @mammadalius, first, have you thought of just hiding the folder and not telling the user where it is? For most users that will do the trick. Also before putting in any effort, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm agree with hiding but it will be revealed by some simple search or checking the size of folders. For example part of my files are saved recording of Telephony conversations with format of .wav and could take a big size on hard disk.